# How to bring python message box in front?

Tags: python-3.x, ctypes, pywin32

I am trying to get windows message box pop in front but every time the message box is called it just pops up in the background on another monitor.

```
import ctypes
from time import sleep

sleep(5) # for switching to another window
MB_SETFOREGROUND = 0x10000
ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(None, "This should be in top", "Very important messsage", MB_SETFOREGROUND)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `MB_SYSTEMMODAL` worked to bring the window to the front.

```py
import ctypes
from time import sleep

sleep(5) # for switching to another window
MB_SYSTEMMODAL = 0x00001000

ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(None, "This should be in top", "Very important message", MB_SYSTEMMODAL)
```

I always recommend using `.argtypes` and `.restype` to ensure parameters are marshaled correctly between Python and C and it allows `ctypes` to better error check parameters:

```py
import ctypes as ct
import ctypes.wintypes as w
import time

dll = ct.WinDLL('user32', use_last_error=True)
dll.MessageBoxW.argtypes = w.HWND, w.LPCWSTR, w.LPCWSTR, w.UINT
dll.MessageBoxW.restype = ct.c_int

MB_SYSTEMMODAL = 0x00001000
IDOK = 1

print('Waiting...')
time.sleep(5)
result = dll.MessageBoxW(None, "This should be in top", "Very important message", MB_SYSTEMMODAL)
print(result == IDOK)
```

Comment: It works but it doesn't focus on the message box if the program isn't in active window. Because of this, users are still able to work on another program without taking action on the message box first. I was looking if the message box will automatically get focused on pop up.

Comment: @Joydeb434 That wasn't clarified in the question.  The dialog box is in front of other windows and can't be covered, but dialog boxes never lock out windows in processes unrelated to the process creating the dialog.